# $Z$-transform of a multilinear function/ consecutive multplication of $k$ signals $y_1(n), \ldots, y_k(n)$

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, z-transform, stability, tensor

How should one go about calculating the $Z$-transform of a signal that is the multiplication of $k$ signals (i.e. a multilinear function with regards to signals $y_1(n) \ldots y_k(n)$ ? Namely, $\mathcal{Z}\{ y_1(n) \cdots y_k(n) \}$ ?

Is there a way to bound the coefficients of the resulting $z$ polynomial?

<strike>Would the complexity be $O( {\text{length-of-$y(\cdot)$} }  ^k)$?</strike>

Comment: does it help that a product in one domain is circular convolution in the other?

Comment: I think there is some context  missing. What is $n$? It looks like a time index $y(n)$ but then the expression $O(n^k)$ makes no sense since $n$ goes from minus infinity to plus infinity.

Comment: yes @Hilmar you are correct. I will omit it anyways because I am not really interested in the computational complexity.

Comment: @DanBoschen, I am aware of this property but I am unsure about moving from $k=2$ to $k \geq 2$.  $y_1(n) \cdot  y_2(n) \cdot y_3(n)$. How does associativity of multiplication carry over to the $z$-domain

Comment: This depends a lot on whether your original sequence finite, infinite aperiodic, or infinite periodic, i.e.. whether the z-transform is continuous or discrete.  Good treatment for the continuous case: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MgjH5dWLJyo